# delphi (2010) program freezes when reading text file

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, freeze

i'm using a user identifying system to not repeat any users but upon identifying a clash delphi completely freezes

```
procedure TForm2.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
  var cool : textfile ;
  svolunteer,scool,sline : string ;
  ipos : integer ;
begin
  svolunteer := string(edtname.text) + ' ' + string(edtAge.Text)  ;

  assignfile(cool, 'cool.txt' )        ;
  try
    reset(cool)
  except
    ShowMessage('file not found') ;
    exit ;
  end;

  while not eof(cool) do
  begin
    reset(cool) ;
    readln(cool, scool) ;
    ipos := pos(',' , sline)        ;
    scool := copy(sline ,1,ipos -1 ) ;
    Delete( sLine,1, iPos -1);
    if svolunteer = scool then begin
      ShowMessage('Username taken') ;
      closefile(cool)
    end;
  end;
  begin
    append(cool) ;
    writeln(cool, svolunteer) ;
    closefile(cool)             ;
  end;
  Button2.Enabled := false ;
end;
```

i have waited minutes on end but it doesn't seem to fix anything

Comment: Start by removing the `reset(cool)` inside your `while` loop - it has the effect of moving the file's read pointer to the start of the file, so the `while not eof(cool)` will always retrun false, giving an infinite loop.

Comment: @MartynA s comment probably resolves the non responsiveness. But there's more: You have a variable `sline: string` declared, and you manipulate its content although you never assign anything to it. You should learn to step through your program, line by line, in the debugger.

Comment: You need to use your debugger. This will show you what is going on. Learning to debug is the single most important thing you can do.

Comment: There's a ``break;`` missing as the last line of the ``if``-block inside the ``while``.-loop

Comment: thanks it no longer freezes! i have fixed my code further and it works!